# How to add date values to new line in a data frame?

Tags: r, date, dataframe

Every time my script runs, a new line containing numeric values is added to my data frame. Another column is supposed to contain the current date. I'm trying to add the date to the newly created line like this:

```
df.answers$date[nrow(df.answers)] <- Sys.Date()
```

This, however, writes `NA`s to all preceding lines of the `date` column and an odd numeric value like `16874` instead of `"2016-03-14"` to the last column.

```
> df.answers
  V1            V2             V3               V4    date
1               50             50               50    NA
2               50             50               50    NA
3               50             50               50    NA
4               50             50               50    16874
```

What am I getting wrong here? How do I write the date correctly in this case?

Comment: The Date class is getting converted to the numeric value stored.  You can convert it back using `as.Date(df.answers$date, origin='1970-01-01')` or use `library(data.table);setDT(df.answers)[.N, date := Sys.Date()]`

Comment: A 2 line option would be `df.answers$date <- Sys.Date();is.na(df.answers$date) <- 1:(nrow(df.answers)-1)`

Comment: This adds the correct date to the last line, but the NA values still persist. I'd like the previous dates not to be overwritten with NAs.

Comment: You are creating a column based on subsetting the last row.  By default, it creates NA for the other values.  I don't know what you want for the other rows.

Comment: Sorry for being so unspecific. New rows get added once every day, so I'd like to write the current date to the `date` column. So, in my example, row 4 would contain today's date, row 3 yesterday's date, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
df.answers$date[nrow(df.answers)] <- format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d")
```

but as @akrun commented below, be advised that this will give you a string value and not a date.